# Insert some data from a MySQL database into an HTML template

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql

I have a main webpage with some links. (E.D. `fist_link`, `second_link`, and etc...)

When I click any link, opens `blank_template.html`, and if I click `fist_link`, on this template inserts the first string from database table.

If click `second_link` also opens `blank_template.html` but with data from the second string from database table.

And so on.

How can I make it? I suppose, that I need to use both JavaScript, and PHP, yes? But I don't know, how?

Comment: Could you please provide a code example, how you are going to do?

Comment: What!? (be more descriptive)

Comment: There is no any code yet, sorry

Comment: @someOne ok one mo description:

Comment: This site helps you with programming problems. We can't help you if you don't have any code you are having a problem with. If you don't know how to code there are some great [tutorials](http://www.w3schools.com/php/) online.

Comment: 1) I have two pages (main and template)
2) On the first page there are some links, if you click the first link, opens the template page(the second) and on it inserts the first row from database table
3) If you click second link, opens the same template page(the second), but now inserts the second row from database table on it .
4) and so on...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***this procedure can be implemented in few ways***, depending on your general guide lines like logic, security, usability, etc..
here is a simple example involving some HTML and PHP:

**the logic:** when the main page is loaded, a PHP script will load the URLs from the data base to the  tag href attribute.

**the code:**

```
<?php
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "your_username", "your_pass", "database_name");
$query = "SELECT id,page_name,url FROM url_table ";
?>
<html>
<head> ... </head>
<body>
.....
<-- <a> tag location on this html page -->
<?php
if ($result = $mysqli->query($query)) {
    while ($row = $result->fetch_row()) {
        echo '<a href="'.$raw[2].'">'.$raw[1].'</a>';
        //the result should be <a href="some_url">link_name</a> for each line in your database
    }
    $result->close();
}
$mysqli->close();
?>
.....
 </body>
</html>
```